# Adding EventHandler for dynamically added control

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I've got a problem with adding some controls into a `Panel`(which gets "PopUpped" by a `ModalPopupExtender`) and add a `CheckedChanged`-EventHandler.

First of all, when user clicks on a button, this happens inside the `CreatePanelChoose()` function:

```
foreach (ListItem item in lbSupplier.Items)
{
    string cbid = "cb" + i;
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.ID = cbid;
    cb.Text = item.Text;
    cb.AutoPostBack = true;

    AjaxControlToolkit.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender mecbe = new AjaxControlToolkit.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender();
    mecbe.ID = "mecbe" + cbid;
    mecbe.TargetControlID = cbid;
    mecbe.Key = "SupplierKEY";
    mecbe.BehaviorID = mecbe.ID + i;

    //Also adding a Label                             

    phModalPopupExtender.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>")); //phModalPopupExtender is a PlaceHolder
    phModalPopupExtender.Controls.Add(cb);
    phModalPopupExtender.Controls.Add(mecbe);
    phModalPopupExtender.Controls.Add(lbl);

    AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    trigger.ControlID = cbid;
    trigger.EventName = "CheckedChanged";
    UpdatePanelMatrix.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    i++;
    ButtonOK.Enabled = false;

}
lblText.Text = "Select one Supplier";
ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

Then i add the `EventHandler` in the `Page_LoadComplete`:

[image: Page_LOadComplete-Code]

As you can see it also gets asigned to the control (I think).
The ModalPopup shows up correctly, but if I click one of the `CheckBox`, then it just closes it without going into `cb_CheckedChanged`, but it makes a Async postback ...
If I check `Request.Form["__ASYNCPOST"]` its true and `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` is also correct. (It gives me the unique id!)

`Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]` is empty.

I think I also need to say that I use a masterpage.

The problem shouldn't be the lifecycle of the page, because msdn says:

> LoadComplete
>
> Raised at the end of the event-handling stage.
>
> Use this event for tasks that require that all other controls on the page be loaded.

Its the onliest place it makes me think it would be right.
Btw: yes i looked trough the topics here allready, but nothing helped me ... (google fo sure also)

**Edit 1:**

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
     if (recreating == true)
     {
          CreatePanelChoose();
     }
}
```

In `CreatePanelChoose` i do the `foreach` now everytime when its a postback! But it still doesnt fire `cb_ChangedChecked` ...

**Edit 2:**

MSDN-Page-Lifecycle also says:

> **PreInit**
>
> Raised after the start stage is complete and before the initialization
>   stage begins.
>
> Use this event for the following:
>
> Create or re-create dynamic controls.

So i tried to recreate the Panel there. But i dont have the ListItems there to get the values ... ?!

Comment: You have to **re**-create all dynamically created controls in `Page_Load`(at the latest) with the same ID's as before. Otherwise events aren't triggered.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the answer! I re-create them now everytime, but still - it doesnt work ...

Answer (score 0):

Okay,  gave up ...
If someone would still have an answer, it would be great!

Right now I dont use the `OnCheckedChanged`-Event of the `CheckBoxes` anymore.
I just let them select a `CheckBox` and on the `OnClick` of the `ButtonOk` I loop through the `CheckBoxes` and check which one is selected.